# 127.0.0.1 and localhost not working

Tags: 14.04, apache2, localhost

I have installed apache2 on my local machine (ubuntu 14.04). I am able to see this screen ("It Works!" screen) by using my network IP (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) but not using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`:

[image: this]

Can anybody help me out please?

**EDIT:**

Here is my [`sudo gedit /etc/apache2/ports.conf`](https://gist.github.com/RajRoR/a1582d5a751a46b90bdc) file.

I have 000-default file instead of 000-default.conf. Here [`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`](https://gist.github.com/RajRoR/f306a2e581a09b672d9a) is.

Comment: seems like apache has been binded to your IP not to 0.0.0.0

Comment: How can I verify it and correct it?

Comment: you should check /etc/apache2/ports.conf file. It would be great if you can pastebin that file. it should look like this. http://paste.ubuntu.com/8526193/

Comment: And /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file should look like this. http://paste.ubuntu.com/8526204/

Comment: @dedunumax Kindly have a look on updated question

Comment: do you have skype installed on your computer?

Comment: some other application is using your localhost:80 socket. http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CouldNotBindToAddress

Comment: Yes, I have skype on the machine

Comment: Please don't run GUI applications like `gedit` with sudo. Use `gksudo` or, even better, `pkexec`.

Answer (score 5):

Run this command to edit ports.conf file
`sudo gedit /etc/apache2/ports.conf`

Add below line in the begining of the file.

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

And make sure that `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` files first line is equal to below line

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html

Comment: After changes, tried restart and faced the error: https://gist.github.com/RajRoR/6f44d9498ae796ff0fb6

Comment: Did you edit 000-default.conf

Comment: I  have 000-default file instead of 000-default.conf. https://gist.github.com/RajRoR/f306a2e581a09b672d9a

Comment: skype usually use port 80. try to kill all the skype processes killall -9 skype. and restart the apache webserver

Comment: Strange! because I always use skype on my all machine and alongwith `localhost` & `127.0.0.1`. Anyways, after killing skype, same problem. I appreciate your effort. Any other work around?

Comment: Try these command to detect what are application currently using your localhost 80 port http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CouldNotBindToAddress

Comment: Here is the output of `sudo lsof -i:80` https://gist.github.com/RajRoR/d816991336b942b8af85

Comment: This saved me because I'v historically for some reason actually changed the default port x)

Answer (score 1):

According to my testing, I have successfully open http://localhost and http://IPaddress by adding the following lines into your httpd.conf file:

```
Listen IPAdress:80  
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

And then restart the httpd service with

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```